# Spigot - Save Blocks that are not full represented by a BlockState - Java

Tags: java, arraylist, minecraft, bukkit

I tried to program something like a "undo"-command. Maybe you know it from WorldEdit. For the saved Blocks I have a `ArrayList<BlockState>`, but if try to save a Chest, Sign, etc it doesn't work. Of course I could add a extra List for Chests `ArrayList<Chest>` and for Signs `ArrayList<Sign>` and for Droppers `ArrayList<Furnace>` ....

Is there a better and easier way to do this?

Thank you for your help and sorry for my bad English ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but you can define an `inteface`, let's say you call it `CommonInterface`, and have all your classes (`BlockState, Chest, Sign ...`) implement this `interface`. Then you can have one object of the type `List<CommonInterface>` (e.g.: `List<CommonInterface> list = new ArrayList<>()`) and save all your objects in this `list`.

**Note**: when you get an object from the `list`, you need to check the run-time type of that object so that you know how to operate with it.

Example:

```
CommonInterface ci = list.get(0);
if(ci instanceof BlockState){
   // do something ...
}
else if(ci instanceof Sign){
   // do something else ... 
}
...
```

Here's another example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestGenerics
{
   class A implements CommonInterface
   {
       public String say()
       {
           return "I'm A";
       }
   }

   class B implements CommonInterface
   {
       public String hi()
       {
           return "I'm B";
       }
   }

   class C implements CommonInterface
   {
       public String getName()
       {
           return "I'm C";
       }
   }

   interface CommonInterface
   {

   }

   public List<CommonInterface> get()
   {
       A a = new A();
       B b = new B();
       C c = new C();
       List<CommonInterface> ci = new ArrayList<>();
       ci.add(a);
       ci.add(b);
       ci.add(c);
       return ci;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       TestGenerics tg = new TestGenerics();
       List<CommonInterface> list = tg.get();
       for(CommonInterface ci : list){
           if(ci instanceof A){
               System.out.println(((A)ci).say());
           }
           else if(ci instanceof B){
               System.out.println(((B)ci).hi());
           }
           else if(ci instanceof C){
               System.out.println(((C)ci).getName());
           }
        } 
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, but I didn't understood what I have to write in the `Interface`. At the moment I only have `public interface AllBlocksList {     }`

Comment: You can have an `interface` with no methods, if all you need is a super-type for all the classes that you want to save in the same list. But if there are common methods that each class has to have, then you can define them in the interface and have the classes implement those methods.

Comment: My example above has the interface with no methods, but it's enough to allow me to save all those objects in one list. **Note**: I have created inner classes just to make the example more concise, otherwise you don't have to do it that way. Write your classes in separate files.

Comment: Okay, I now have `... extends BlockState, Chest, ...`, but what if these Superclasses have same Methods? Eclipse shows a Error to me: `The return types are incompatible for the inherited methods BrewingStand.getInventory(), Furnace.getInventory()`

Comment: I don't understand it, why do you have `something extends BlockState` !!! You should have `BlockState implements AllBlocksList`. In this case `AllBlockList` is a super-type for all the classes that implement this interface. So, the `List<AllBlocksList> list` object can save any object which is a sub-type of `AllBlocksList`. But when you get an object from this list, check its run-time type using the keyword `instanceof`, as in my example.

Comment: Maybe I'm really a Idiot, or it's just because I never created a Interface before :D. So is it right that I in the Interface `AllBlocksList`, I only write ´public interface AllBlocksList {     }` and then I also have to create a own class for ´BlockState`, `Sign`, ...? Like this `public class BlockState implements AllBlocksList {     }`? Thank you and sorry that I don't understand it yet :/

Comment: Correct, if your interface is only and only to allow you to save those objects in one list. This way, you don't have to create `ArrayList<BlockState>, ArrayList<Sign>, ArrayList<Chest> ... ` but only one `ArrayList<AllBlocksList>`, and save all those objects in that one list.

Comment: And I also didn't have to write anything else than the get-Method in the Classes? Not something that shows that my Class `BlockState` represents a `org.bukkit.block.BlockState`?

Comment: I think you are asking too many different questions now. What we have discussed so far, is to give you a better way of saving objects of different types in one array. If you have other questions, please be more specific and post them as new questions. Thank you!

Comment: `BlockState`, `Chest` etc. are all interfaces from the Bukkit/Spigot API, so it's not really possible to have those interfaces implement one's own custom interface, they would have to be in your own project and not be interfaces.

Comment: How do you use these interfaces (`BlockState, Chest` etc.)? Do you have an implementation or you write classes that implement them? If you are writing your own classes that implement the Spigot API interfaces, then you can have your classes implement a common interface, in addition to all others that you have to implement.

In case you are using an implementation, then you can have an array of objects `List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>()` and save any object in that list, but you have to check the run-time type when you get an element from that list and want to operate with it.